# Detecting internal transactions given a debug_traceTransaction response

Tags: geth-debugging, internal-transactions, decoding, transaction-trace

## Intro

Hello everyone, I am attempting to filter and recreate internal transactions given a `debug_traceTransaction` response and the `{tracer: "callTracer"}` tracer. An example transaction can be found here: https://snowtrace.io/tx/0x20177106356d1d2d7c809dd870a7b68a12245c1a965ebd7a02aa987572616f44#internal

I understand that this is the Avalanche C-chain and not Ethereum, but both are EVMs and I assume that there is no significant difference. I have created a solution that filters calls given an output from the `debug_traceTransaction` that seemingly works fine, but I would like to confirm my findings with the community since my approach is only empirical. The filter I am applying:

1. A call must not be at the top of the stack.
2. A call must have a defined value associated with it.
3. A call must have a value different from 0 associated with it.

## The question

What is the minimum filter that can be applied to a `debug_traceTransaction` response with the `{tracer: "callTracer"}` tracer to uniquely identify and recreate internal transactions, such that the internal transactions recreated this way contain at least the fields `from`, `to` and `value`?